# Why did Tomoe Gozen not kill the old couple?

Tags: fate-series

During the events of the third Pseudo-Singularity "Shimousa", [Tomoe Gozen](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Tomoe_Gozen) and [Katou Danzou](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Katou_Danzou) are heading towards Shimousa's southern border, where they are approached by an elderly couple. Danzou believes that this is terrible luck for the old couple, thinking Tomoe would kill them immediately.

However, Tomoe instead tells the elderly couple to be careful, especially at night, as monsters are roaming about. The couple offers both of them to stay at their house for the night, which Tomoe politely declines.

Tomoe then asks Danzo if they are heading towards a village - presumably the one the elderly couple came from - which Danzo confirms. Tomore then decides to head towards this village and murder everyone there.

Afterwards, Danzo records a log entry, in which she states the following:

> [...] However, the Archer of Inferno *(Tomoe Gozen)* did not complete her massacre. Quite unexpectedly, she did not kill the elderly couple we had met earlier.

Tomoe replies:

> What are you saiyng, Lady Danzo? We exchanged pleasantries and expressed concern for one another. Why ever would we want to hurt them? You ninja certainly say the oddest things. If I did something that cruel, I would be condemned to hell.

---

This reasoning strikes me as a little odd. Tomoe Gozen had no issues murdering an entire village, including elderly and children, yet felt completely bewildered at the idea of killing the two people she had met before. Why exactly did she not kill them?

Is this merely meant to illustrate that those affected by the Curse of annihilation act irrationally? I find that very hard to believe, especially since

> Raikō, who is also affected by the same curse, seems to act very rational. She completely refuses to harm two children, and threatens to kill her co-conspirator Shuten-Dōji, after she expressed a desire to kill said children.

Is there something specific about Tomoe Gozen's past, which is similar to the above-mentioned situation, causing her to act especially kind to this old couple? Or is there something I am just not *getting* about this whole situation?